# What do "take ground" and "vested in" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, vocabulary, legalese

Here is an extract from the headnote of a case [1] I am trying to understand:

> The defendants, who were wharfingers, agreed with the plaintiff for a
>   consideration to allow his vessel to discharge and load her cargo at
>   their wharf, which abutted upon the River Thames. It was necessary in
>   order that the vessel might be unloaded that she should be moored
>   alongside a jetty of the defendants which ran into the river, and that
>   ***she should take ground with her cargo at the ebb of the tide***.

Additionally, if anyone could help illuminate this next part for me, I'd be most grateful:

> ***The bed of the river at the point where she took ground was vested in the Conservators***, and the defendants had no control over it, but it
>   was admitted that they had taken no steps to ascertain whether it was
>   suitable for the vessel to ground upon.

[1]  “[The Moorcock](http://books.google.com/books?id=If1GAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA157&lpg=PA157&dq=Law+Reports%3a+Probate,+Divorce++Admiralty+Division+%22+Moorcock%22&source=bl&ots=eJ1vh9jPsY&sig=YySuJGiSrMcU2dV-sT8pnDqjH9M&hl=en&sa=X&ei=d828ULfKBKnriwL_4IGYDQ&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=Law%20Reports%3A%20Probate%2C%20Divorce%20%20Admiralty%20Division%20%22%20Moorcock%22&f=false)”,  **The Law Reports. Probate Division in the Courts of Probate, Divorce, and Admiralty Division, Great Britain**, Volume 13, page 157 (July 1888)

Comment: Please edit question and add a source reference, and if possible a source link.

Comment: the source link would be lexis nexis, which I'm not sure I could link to directly, as the the site requires special access (ie through university libraries/law faculties), so I have uploaded it here: http://www.filedropper.com/themoorcock188813pd157

Comment: I added a Google Books link.  Do you know if Lexis/Nexis allows posting multi-page extracts from their system?  Perhaps check their rules.

Answer (score 5):

*Take (the) ground* is equivalent to *ground* as a verb; sometimes barges and the like cannot be properly unloaded while they are floating. *At the ebb of the tide* is obviously *at low tide*.

*Vesting* is a legal term you really need to look up, but for non-technical purposes such as EL&U can help with, *vested in* is equivalent to *owned by*.